# Datatable retorno de select

Tags: ajax, select, datatable

Estou utilizando a datatable com ajax, obtendo entre outros uma coluna com select, mas não sei porque `onchange` não funciona. Segue o retorno do ajax:

```
{"data":
  [[
    1,
    "17020161",
    "Marina Costa Vasconcelos",
    "<select data-id='17020161' id='status_aluno17020161' style='background-color: #00C851; color:white' class='form-control status' ><option style='background-color: #00C851; color:white' value='1' >Presente<\/option>\n<option style='background-color: #ff4444; color:white' value='2'>Falta<\/option><\/select>",
    "",
    "",
    ""
  ],[
    2,
    "12080243",
    "Talita de Souza Menezes",
    "<select data-id='12080243' id='status_aluno12080243' style='background-color: #00C851; color:white' class='form-control status' ><option style='background-color: #00C851; color:white' value='1' >Presente<\/option>\n<option style='background-color: #ff4444; color:white' value='2'>Falta<\/option><\/select>",
    "",
    "",
    ""
  ]]
}
```

Nisso a função abaixo não funciona:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.status').on('change', function() {
        //$(".status").change(function(){
            var valor = this.value;
            var matricula = $(this).data("id");
            alert(matricula);
            alert(valor);

            if (valor == 1) { 
                $("#status_aluno"+matricula).css("background-color", "#00C851"); 
            } 
            if (valor == 2) { 
                    $("#status_aluno"+matricula).css("background-color", "#ff4444");
            }
            if (valor == 3) { 
                    $("#status_aluno"+matricula).css("background-color", "#00C851"); 
            } 
            if (valor == 4) { 
                    $("#status_aluno"+matricula).css("background-color", "#ffbb33"); 
            }
            if (valor == 5) { 
                    $("#status_aluno"+matricula).css("background-color", "#ffbb33"); 
            }
            if (valor == 6) { 
                    $("#status_aluno"+matricula).css("background-color", "#ff4444"); 
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Imaginei q era algo nesse sentido, funcionou, muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Ela não funciona, pois você não está adicionando a função no seu `select`, pois este javascript roda antes dele existir no documento.

O modo que isso funcionaria seria usando eventos delegados. Você adiciona o handler do evento no elemento pai, e usa um seletor para designar quando ele irá disparar. Seria algo assim:

```
$(document).on('change', '.status', function() {
   // aqui mantém tudo
}
```

Aqui adiciono o evento no `document`, mas ele só vai disparar quando o seletor `'.status'` for encontrado, e funciona mesmo para elementos adicionados depois de anexar o evento no `document`. Outro detalhe, seria ainda mais interessante você adicionar no `<form>`, ao invés de `document`, onde este seu `<select>` vai estar.

### Maiores informações

http://api.jquery.com/on/